# Cannot connect more than 3 BLE devices to web app

Tags: javascript, bluetooth-lowenergy, web-bluetooth, domexception

I'm having troubles connecting 6 BLE devices using web Bluetooth API. I manage to connect 3 but after the 3rd I get this error:
**DOMException: Connection failed for unknown reason.**
The laptop I use mounts a bluetooth 5.1. I tried with previous versions on other laptops and the pairing and connection worked for all the sensors. Why this happens it's still a mistery to me. Have you ever experienced this issue?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Have you successfully connected 6 bluetooth devices in this machine using anything else other than the web API? Maybe the limitation is in the hardware and not in the API.

Comment: I tried with the desktop app from Nordic, but since these sensors cannot be paired and Windows 10 likes paired devices only I couldn't test them. I'm looking for a quick work around on Ubuntu just to connect them and see if I can receive notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue getting myself a bluetooth dongle. I guess the combo chip bluetooth+Wifi doesn't respond well to the type of job I was trying to do. So as one of the nice people that answered to my question suggested, it was indeed a hardware problem. With the dongle I managed to connect 5 devices and to receive data. Thanks to all of you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Bluetooth controller you have attached to the computer has a maximum number of connections of 3 devices.

Unfortunately the web bluetooth apis don't forward the error code from the controller, but just says "unknown error" when a failure happens.

Comment: Do you know how to get natively controller errors? If so, we could add some details to Web Bluetooth errors.

Comment: Hi Emil, thank you for the hint. My laptop is a Dell Latitude 3301 with the following Hardware:
Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] [8086:9df0] (rev 30)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] [8086:4030]
Unfortunately I was not able to determine the number of simultaneous max connections. 
At first I thought it was an Ubuntu issue, but then I tested the code on the Windows partition and it did not work as well.

Comment: It's a bit hard since many Bluetooth stack implementations running on common OSes, like Android and Windows don't really gracefully handle or document the situations when the maximum number of connections have been reached, and in particular don't return a specific error code when the controller says so. Apple's CoreBluetooth is better however, it has a specific error code for this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cberror/cberrorconnectionlimitreached?language=objc. You could try yourself on different OS platforms and see what happens when you reach the limit.